# What encoding is text messaging in?

Tags: sms

The reason for the question is that I have a friend with an iPhone who sends emoticons, and I receive them as a single rectangular box.  I wonder if it's an encoding problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

iPhone emoticons are not character combinations like `:-)` but they are single UTF-16 character of emoticons called [**Emoji**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Emoji) which are not by default supported in Android.

By using some third party sms apps such as [GO SMS PRO](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms) and installing its [Emoji Plugin](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jb.gosms.emoji&feature=more_from_developer) you would be able to send and receive such iPhone emoticons to/from your friend.

Answer (score 5):

SMS, generally, uses the 7-bit GSM encoding standard, however a quick cursory glance with google-fu yielded this answer posted on [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4614439/what-encoding-is-used-in-sms-of-iphone) which seems to say that Apple uses UTF-16 (Unicode encoding).

This would explain why you got a rectangular box as the handset is not able to decipher the encoding.

You can find out more here as per the [standards document](http://www.3gpp.org/ftp/specs/archive/23_series/23.038/23038-a00.zip)